# Adding previous 7 days unless 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to develop an hours log tracker for drivers.

Using excel 7 - I need to calculate the 7 previous days from the current (its a sliding scale), if there are zero hours in a day then the hours reset to zero and start adding again for 7 days.

Does it make sense?

How do I write a formula to say add the previous 7 unless zero start at 0 and count 7 days.
I want it to look like this:

```
      hours worked  70hrs/7days 
Jan 1     10           10
Jan 2     12           22 
Jan 3      4           26
Jan 4      4           30
Jan 5      0            0
Jan 6      8            8
Jan 7     10           18
Jan 8     12           30
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean my current? e.g. if you were to say Jan 4 is current in your example, you are actually counting only 4 days.

Comment: The problems I'm having with this is that you need previous 7 days **only if they exist** and **only back to a 0 day**, right? I think this is why you can't find any "dot 70 hour rule excel formula" results that are good solutions. You'll need some helper columns across the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need a helper column, in my example, the helper column is in column D.

Put the following formula in cell D2 and drag down:

```
=IF(B2=0,0,IF(D1=7,1,IFERROR(D1+1,1)))
```

In cell C2, put this formula and drag down:

```
=IF(OR(B2=0,D2=7),B2,C1+B2)
```

For the following data samples, you get the following output:

```
        hours worked  70hrs/7days  Helper
Jan 01       10           10          1
Jan 02       12           22          2
Jan 03        4           26          3
Jan 04        4           30          4
Jan 05        0            0          0
Jan 06        8            8          1
Jan 07       10           18          2
Jan 08       12           30          3
Jan 09       10           40          4
Jan 10        3           43          5
Jan 11       24           67          6
Jan 12        2            2          7
Jan 13        7            9          1
Jan 14        6           15          2
Jan 15        3           18          3
Jan 16       18           36          4
Jan 17       10           46          5
Jan 18       20           66          6
Jan 19       11           11          7
```

Basically, the helper column keeps track of how many days in a row there has been hours, which feeds the 70hrs/7days formula.

There's a solution without a helper column, but it is likely to be *very* long. I'm thinking about the functions `MOD` with the number of `ROWS`, and array formula to get the last seen `0`.

---

reEDIT: The single formula I can think of is:

```
=IF(B8=0,0,IF(COUNTIF(C1:C7,0)=0,IF(MOD(ROWS(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(9^99,IF(C$1:C7=0,1))+1&":"&CELL("address",C7))),7)=0,B8,C7+B8),C7+B8))
```

entered as array formula (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) as from cell `C8`. Cell C2 will have the formula `=IF(B2=0,0,B1+B2)` and dragged up to until at most C7.

Comment: She needs it only upto 7 days..

Comment: My bad. Got it..

Comment: I think there is another problem. I could very well be wrong. If there are no zeroes encountered then the formula will just keep adding up whereas she needs it for just 7 days. How are you getting 7 in column C for Jan 13?

Comment: You can try `SUM(INDIRECT("C8:C"&MATCH(0,C8:C1,0)))` in `else` part of `COUNTIF(C1:C7,0)=0`

Comment: I can't come up with any solution without a helper column or VBA.

Comment: @Raystafarian Added the single formula solution, if you're interested.

Comment: That is pretty impressive. And it works with consecutive 0s

Comment: thanks alot for all your help! A little over my head lol but I'm going to get it working on it right now that's great!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, for each row, you need sum of hours from previous 7 days unless there were 0 hours for any of those 7 days.
If there are 0 hours then you want sum of hours upto 0 hours entry.
Is my understanding right?

If yes then this seems a little difficult to achieve using plain formulae(other answers may come up clever formulae though). Are you familiar with VBA macros. If not, I am other SU members can help you with one.

Here is pseudo-code of what you need:

```
For each cell in column C (
if zero is found in previous 7 cells then
(find index of zero cell
current cell value = sum up to zero cell index)
else 
(current cell value =  sum of previous 7 cells)
)
```

Then you can tie thus macro to spreadsheet change event which means the column will e updated every time you change the sheet contents.